minimum value of $c$ under constraint $a^2+ab+b^2=3c^2$ for $a,b,c$ positive integer and $a\neq b$
My idea is to let $c^2=ab$ so the constraint become $a^2+b^2=2c^2$.
I deduce that the solution must be in the form
$a=p+q, b=p-q$ where $p^2+q^2=c^2$
but it lead to $p^2-q^2=(p+q)(p-q)=ab=c^2=p^2+q^2$ giving $q=0$. In the end we have $a=p=b$ which contradicts the condition $a\neq b$
I also tried another manipulation like
$a^3-b^3=3(a-b)c^2$ but it doesnt help at all.

A brute force gives $a=2, b=11$ and $c=7$ as $4 + 22 + 121 = 147 = 3\cdot 49.$
Imposing $c^2=ab$  seems restricting.

thankyou very much, I did several brute force but fails. Imposing $c^2=ab$ because of desperation lol. @F_M_

As noted in the comments, $\{a,b\}=\{2,13\}$ gives $c=7$.
The minimal solution must have $a,b,c$ pairwise relatively prime and clearly $>1$. Let $p$ be a prime factor of $c$; then
$a^2+ab+b^2\equiv0\bmod p\implies a^3\equiv b^3\bmod p$.
Distinct values of $a$ and $b$ must have distinct residues $\bmod p$ for at least one of the prime factors of $c$. So $ab^{-1}$ is a cube root of unity other than $1$ itself, which exists $\bmod p$ only if the prime $p$ is one greater than a multiple of $3$. Thus $c$ must have a prime factor of at least $7$, forcing the above quoted solution to be minimal.

Thankyou very much for the answer. Actually, the original problem gives more restriction namely $ 3 \nmid b+c$. Does it mean that I need to do brute force for $p=11, 13, 17$ etc until I obtain the answer? Because that is what I deduce from your explanation @Oscar Lanzi

BlNot $11$ or $17$. Must have a $3n+1$ prime factor so $c=13$ would be next. This has a solutions in which no two terms add up to a multiple of 3, which you should be able to find.
